# How do I change the background image on a single workspace?

Tags: workspaces, desktop-background

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is it possible to have a different background for each workspace?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/75998/is-it-possible-to-have-a-different-background-for-each-workspace)

I would like a different background for each of my workspaces- is this possible?

Thanks,
Colleen