# Is it possible to have a different background for each workspace?

Tags: workspaces, desktop-background

I normally use 4 different workspaces for different things, and they are always the same. Can I make a different background image for each one of them?

I would like an answer that works for GNOME 3 desktop environment, Unity and the Classic desktop environment.

---

This question has multiple answers covering different Ubuntu versions:

- [17.10, 18.04 and later](https://askubuntu.com/a/1089402/1089402)
- [13.04, 13.10 and 14.04](https://askubuntu.com/a/334224/14356)
- [12.10](https://askubuntu.com/a/213514/14356)
- [12.04](https://askubuntu.com/a/159255/14356)
- [11.10](https://askubuntu.com/a/76049/14356)
- [11.04](https://askubuntu.com/a/76001/14356)
- [10.04](https://askubuntu.com/a/4500/14356)

Comment: What about Ubuntu 16.04?

Comment: Or for that matter, 18.04?

Answer (score 33):

## Ubuntu 10.04

You can get the Wallpaper plugin for Compiz by installing [compiz-fusion-plugins-extra](http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/compiz-fusion-plugins-extra) (`sudo apt-get install compiz-fusion-plugins-extra`). It will show up under the Utility category in CompizConfig Settings Manager.

Before you can use it, you'll have to configure Nautilus to not draw the desktop. Run `gconf-editor` and uncheck the setting `/apps/nautilus/preferences/show_desktop`. This will make all of your desktop icons disappear, and there is no solution to this drawback at this time.

To configure the Wallpaper plugin, add images to the list of backgrounds. They will be assigned to workspaces in the order they are listed, and you don't have to have the exact right number:

[image: CompizConfig]

The result:

[image: Expo]

Comment: This is great! I don't use desktop icons to begin with - so this is quite a sufficient solution!

Comment: Sucks we can't keep the desktop icons (http://brainstorm.ubuntu.com/idea/93/)

Comment: I once had working patches to make nautilus draw a transparent desktop when in a compositing environment so we could get desktop icons and wallpaper specific icons. Unfortunately they were never accepted and modern nautilus needs more changes I haven't dug in to to get the same job done.

Comment: I don't see the setting in 12.04.

Comment: For 12.04 read this: http://askubuntu.com/questions/116741/how-to-hide-all-desktop-icons-in-12-04

Comment: On what version of Ubuntu will this work? I'm interested in 12.04, but others might want another version.

Comment: @ændrük will this work on 12.04? or what is it meant for?

Comment: @Alvar I originally wrote this for Ubuntu 10.04 in response to [this question](http://askubuntu.com/q/4497/1859). It looks like there is now a [similar answer pertaining to Ubuntu 12.04](http://askubuntu.com/a/159255/1859) that accounts for the [new configuration system](http://askubuntu.com/q/22313/1859) introduced in that release.

Comment: @ændrük Sorry for off-topic but ... Where can i found these awesome wallpapers ?

Comment: @bux Those are [watercolor paintings by David S. Goodsell](http://mgl.scripps.edu/people/goodsell/) and [a wallpaper by Souhail Moumit](http://souhail88.deviantart.com/art/Colorful-89744212).

Answer (score 31):

### 12.04

[image]

#### how-to

Launch `dconf-editor` (install [dconf-tools](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/dconf-tools) [image: Install dconf-tools] if required)

[image]

Navigate to `org - gnome - desktop - background`

Now the very strange bit - by default the `show-desktop-icons` is unticked.  Click it to tick it and click it again to untick it.

Now install some extra software:

#### [compizconfig-settings-manager](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/compizconfig-settings-manager) [image: Install compizconfig-settings-manager]

#### [compiz-fusion-plugins-extra](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/compiz-fusion-plugins-extra) [image: Install compiz-fusion-plugins-extra]

Launch the Dash and search for `ccsm`

Filter to `wallpaper` - enable the wallpaper plugin and add *New* wallpaper as shown.

[image]

Notes:

- during testing, when I enabled *wallpaper* the desktop froze solid.  I had no choice but to do a hard-reset via the power button.
- remember this important bit of information:

  - Log out and back in again to show new wallpapers

[What are some of the issues with CCSM and why would I want to avoid it?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/80589/what-are-some-of-the-issues-with-ccsm-and-why-should-i-not-use-it)

---

If you prefer not to risk `ccsm` then you can use `gconf-editor` (you can install it by running `sudo apt-get install gconf-editor`).

#### [gconf-editor](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/gconf-editor) [image: Install gconf-editor]

[image]

Add the two plugins as shown.

[image]

Add a comma-separated  list with the full-paths to your wallpaper as shown.

Comment: "During testing, when I enabled wallpaper the desktop froze solid. I had no choice but to do a hard-reset via the power button" ... which perfectly illustrates the issues with using ccsm!

Comment: For me, this only works with the wallpapers provided in /usr/share/wallpapers. Doesn't work with wallpapers off the web, just shows black screen. Any idea on how to fix?

Comment: The wallpapers have to be on a permanantly mounted drive, so that the wallpaper plugin can fetch it as soon as the user logs in. Refer to [Ubuntu Wiki's Automatically Mount Partitions page](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/AutomaticallyMountPartitions)

Comment: The "Show Desktop Icons" was already ticked for me, still no desktop icons while using workspaces.

Answer (score 22):

### Ubuntu 13.04, 13.10 and 14.04

[image]

#### How to

Launch `dconf-editor` (install [dconf-tools](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/dconf-tools) [image: Install dconf-tools] if required)

[image]

Navigate to `org - gnome - desktop - background`

Now the very strange bit - by default the `show-desktop-icons` is unticked.  Click it to tick it and click it again to untick it.

Now install some extra software: [compizconfig-settings-manager](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/compizconfig-settings-manager) [image: Install compizconfig-settings-manager]

Ensure you have the following package installed: [compiz-plugins](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/compiz-plugins) [image: Install compiz-plugins]

Launch the Dash and search for `ccsm`

Filter to `wallpaper` - enable the wallpaper plugin and add *New* wallpaper as shown.

[image]

[What are some of the issues with CCSM and why would I want to avoid it?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/80589/what-are-some-of-the-issues-with-ccsm-and-why-should-i-not-use-it)

Finally - enable the use of workspaces in your System Settings (Cog Wheel menu option)

[image: pic]

Note: the [12.04 answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/159255/14356) described using the gsettings editor as an alternative to ccsm.  The equivalent for 14.04 is `dconf-editor`.
It is not possible (at least not easily) due to compiz using relocatable schemas. The 'wallpaper' option under 'org.compiz.profiles.unity.plugins' will only appear when you have added a wallpaper via ccsm.

Comment: This didn't work on Ubuntu 14.10... Any solution?

Comment: How would this work if you had a program such as Variety which changes the desktop background? Would it change it independently for each workspace?

Comment: Hmmm... am I missing something?  No one has been interested in this since 14.xx??  I'm using 17.10 and I cannot find the ccsm-plugins-xxx to install.  In ccsm, I have a "wall" setting but no "wallpaper" setting?  Is there someone who could update this thread with a 17.10 solution?

Answer (score 15):

### 11.10

- You will need `compizconfig-settings-manager and compiz-plugins-extra`
- First see: [What are some of the issues with CCSM and why would I want to avoid it?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/80589/what-are-some-of-the-issues-with-ccsm-and-why-should-i-not-use-it)

  `sudo apt-get install compizconfig-settings-manager compiz-fusion-plugins-extra`
- Press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> key combination and type `gconf-editor` in “Run a command” box.

In next window, navigate to “apps/nautilus/appearances” and un-check “show_dekstop” in right.
[image]

- Open Compiz and search `Wallpaper` plugin
  [image]
- Click “New” to choose a wallpaper for your first workspace.

[image]

- Browse to select an image.
  [image]

Repeat this step for all your workspaces. Once done, enable the wallpaper plugin.

---

For those who don't have "show_desktop" in Configuration Editor-

1. Install *gnome-tweak-tool*, enter in terminal-
   `sudo apt-get install gnome-tweak-tool`
2. Key <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> and enter `gnome-tweak-tool` and hit enter.
3. Click on ▸ Desktop ▸ Have file manager handle the desktop ▸ switch to **Off**

[image: picture of gnome-tweak-tool dialog box]

4.Proceed with the above instructions for changing compiz settings.

Comment: It seems this approach makes Docky not work, and one can't see files and folders on the Desktop. (I'm using Gnome-Classic on 12.04). Is there an option and solution to having this feature without losing Desktop functionality, or accessories like Docky?

Answer (score 8):

## Ubuntu 12.10

This is not currently possible. Due to [bug #1020830](https://bugs.launchpad.net/compiz/+bug/1020830), the necessary Compiz plugin is not available.

Comment: This bug has been fixed acording to launchpad `This bug was fixed in the package compiz - 1:0.9.9~daily13.01.14-0ubuntu1`. Is it possible now?

Answer (score 7):

### Ubuntu 17.10 and later

Install the **Walkpaper** GNOME Shell Extension from Ubuntu Software. Set a different wallpaper for each workspace by having the wallpaper switch on workspace change. After installing Walkpaper click the  <kbd>Extension Settings</kbd>  button in the Walkpaper screen in Ubuntu Software to open a Walkpaper window. In the Walkpaper window you can change the settings for each workspace by double-clicking on the current wallpaper and browsing to a new wallpaper image.

[image]

Walkpaper gives an error in GNOME Shell 3.30 on loading – `global.screen is undefined`. A simple user workaround is to run `gedit ~/.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions/walkpaper*/extension.js` and find and replace all occurrences of `global.screen` with `global.workspace_manager`. Restart gnome-shell with `setsid gnome-shell --replace` and press the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key before closing the terminal, and it should work.

Comment: A simpler way to restart GNOME Shell is to hit ALT-F2, and enter "r" into the box that appears. "r" means restart.

Comment: I like this solution, but I would like to have different wallpaper [settings](https://askubuntu.com/a/1023090/719469) for each workspace. Is that possible?

Comment: When you change the settings for one workspace that also changes the settings for all the other workspaces, except for the wallpaper itself which can be different wallpapers for different workspaces.

Answer (score 2):

1. Install Compiz Settings Manager:

   > sudo apt-get install compizconfig-settings-manager
2. Press Atl + F2 and run:

   > gconf-editor
3. Navigate to apps > nautilus > preferences and uncheck show_dekstop.
4. Next, open the Compiz Setting Manager and go to the Wallpaper plugin.
5. Click “New” to choose a wallpaper for your first workspace.
6. Browse to select an image.
7. Repeat the steps for all your workspaces. Once done, enable the wallpaper plugin.
8. Unity’s theme will look weird after enabling the plugin. Restarting the computer will fix it.

Source: http://joesteiger.com/2011/07/18/enable-different-wallpapers-for-each-workspace-in-unity-ubuntu-11-04/

Hope this helps,

Leinardo

Comment: Having problems with following steps in Ubuntu 12.04. 1>gconf-editor doesnt have an option of show desktop in preferences in nautilus.
2> In compiz cant get any wallpaper plugin
Any suggestions?

Comment: In 12.04, there is no "show_desktop" in apps > nautilus unfortunately.

Comment: In later versions this option is available via (Gnome) Tweak Tool under "Desktop > Have file manager handle the desktop".

Comment: Yahtzee! In 12.04 The above instructions worked very well, What I can add is, if you are having trouble finding the show desktop setting. Try this- Click Application Menu, Then System Tools, Find Preferences, Then click on Preferences, And look for advanced settings. After you click Advanced Setting. Once in advanced setting. You will the desktop icon and you can make your adjustment there..

Answer (score 1):

### Ubuntu 11.04

I know this is possible with `compiz`. Do you have/use compiz? if so (install and) open `compizconfig-settings-manager` and look under the wallpaper plugin.

If I recall, adding multiple wallpapers would set them in order (ie. the first image selected goes to workspace one, the second image goes to workspace two). You might need to muck about in the settings to get compiz to render your wallpaper.

Open the Terminal and type this command:

```
 sudo apt-get install compiz compiz-core compizconfig-settings-manager compiz-plugins
```

Then navigate to :

- system -> preferences -> compizconfig  in settings manager.

Type "wallpaper" in the search, click the wallpaper plugin, enable it on the left, select your wall papers.

I believe you may need to change more settings in the gnome compatibility options or something like that, but I can't recall exactly.

Comment: Please list the commands necessary and list all the software that I need if I have a fresh install of 11.04.

Comment: always assume that I don't have extra software installed.

Comment: right, sorry. Uh, fresh from 11.04? sudo apt-get install compiz compiz-core compizconfig-settings-manager compiz-plugins should do it for installation, then navigate to system -> preferences -> compizconfig settings manager. type "wallpaper" in the search, click the wallpaper plugin, enable it on the left, select your wall papers. I believe you may need to change more settings up in the gnome compatibility options or something, i don't recall exactly and don't have anything i can test it on

Comment: add it in your answer and improve the horrible formatting.