# How to hide all desktop icons in 12.04 and later?

Tags: unity, nautilus, icons, desktop-icons

In 11.10 Using Configuration editor, one used to be able to edit a boolean parameter named : `Desktop_Show` 
This allowed to hide/show all desktop icons.
This latter was removed in 12.04.
[image: Config Editor in 12.04]

Someone, knows how to hide desktop icons automatically?

Thanks

Comment: This looks answered anyway, but that looks like `gconf-editor`, which is probably why it did not work...

Answer (score 62, accepted):

It's in gsettings (& dconf-editor), to do from cli use

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.background show-desktop-icons false
```

From gui open `dconf-editor` (install `dconf-tools`) as in screen

[image: dconf-editor]

Comment: (Bumpy bump!)   When I use this is the final version of Ubuntu 13.04, I can only bring up the launcher one time if the desktop icons are disabled. I then have to alt+TAB to a window, then back to the desktop to bring it up again. The launcher works normally in applications.

Comment: It's funny... i had 2 set of icons overlaped on my Ubuntu 16.04 Unity desktop, but when i ran this, one of them disappeared and problem solved :) Thank you!

Comment: On Ubuntu 16.04, `show-desktop-icons` seems to get reset to `true` every time I log out.  Additionally, in order to hide the icons, I need to `killall nautilus` and then restart `nautilus` after running `gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.background show-desktop-icons false`.  Perhaps I am doing something wrong?

Comment: This should work in both Unity and GNOME Shell

Answer (score 2):

The MyUnity application (in the software center) has a lot of useful features for customizing Unity, including the ability to hide desktop icons. The newest version supports 12.04.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I already have MyUnity, Ubuntu Tweak and Unity Settings. What they offer is to show/hide (home, network, trash and computer) icons. 
While, I am interested in hiding all icons in dekstop (files, folders.....etc).

Answer (score 1):

If you are using the Gnome desktop environment then

1. Open the Tweak tool
2. Click on the Desktop tab
3. Toggle the "Icons on Desktop" button to off.

[image: Tweak Tool settings menu]