# How can I remove my hard drive icons from my desktop?

Tags: hard-drive, icons, removing

I'd like to remove some of the icons on my desktop but I cant seem to find out how. Specifically I'm talking about my hard drive, its partitions, and the file system. Any help would be great! I'm using Ubuntu 12.04, by the way.

Comment: Can you show a screenshot of what you currently have?

Comment: Something like [this](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/ubuntu/hide-removable-drive-icons-from-your-ubuntu-desktop/), I suppose. Also, see [this answer](http://askubuntu.com/questions/195988/how-to-remove-launcher-drive-icons).

Comment: Yes, that what it looks like. I tried following the steps to black list, but when I get into my canonical folder, the only section inside of it is "indicator"

Answer (score 0):

I found this while searching in google

[How to hide all desktop icons in 12.04 and later?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/116741/how-to-hide-all-desktop-icons-in-12-04)

http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1871789

Comment: While I did check the boxes, nothing seemed to happen.

Comment: have you read the answer? the one asking you to use gsettings

Comment: You also have to save the changes you applied in gconf-editor, but pushing the button ''