# Disable icons on desktop Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, unity, desktop-background, desktop-icons

I am trying to figure out how to disable desktop icons in Ubuntu 14.04. I found option `show-desktop-icons` in dconf editor under `org.gnome.desktop.background`. Unfortunately this disables also custom background and also makes unity really laggy and unusable.

Any other suggestions?

Comment: So, I see that you know [how to disable icons](http://askubuntu.com/q/116741/147044) from your desktop, but what is happen to you seems to be a bug, and bugs are [off topic](http://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic) here. See [How do I report a bug?](http://askubuntu.com/q/5121/147044)

Comment: how can I be sure it's a bug? Maybe it's a feature to not able user to have this two options together.

Comment: You have to trust me: there is no feature in this sense. [This answer](http://askubuntu.com/a/116891/147044) works perfectly for me in 14.04.

Comment: seems like last update,  7.2.0+14.04.20140416-0ubuntu1 , has it fixed

Answer (score -1):

7.2.0+14.04.20140416-0ubuntu1 has it already fixed

Comment: @muru Ah, missed that fact. Thanks for clarifying.

Comment: Still here is in `7.2.5+14.04.20150603-0ubuntu1`

Comment: Not fixed.  Using 14.04 completely up to date.