# how to set different wallpapers in ubuntu workspaces

Tags: 12.04, desktop-background

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is it possible to have a different background for each workspace?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/75998/is-it-possible-to-have-a-different-background-for-each-workspace)

I'm having an issues trying to customize ubuntu workspaces in the gnome environment.  Assuming the default four workspaces aka desktops, how can one have a different wallpaper for each one?  When I go to an individual workspace to set its wallpaper, all of the workspaces use it.

So if I set:

- wallpaper B on workspace 2
- wallpaper C on workspace 3

What will happen is that all the workspaces will default to the last wallpaper set no matter which workspace it was set in.

What's even weirder is that the very first wallpaper set upon using it for the very first time is what shows up when i call up the Workspaces tool. Even though once I settle upon a workspace, no matter which one, the original wallpaper disappears and the last wallpaper set is the one that always shows up.