# Conky not appearing on Compiz wallpapers?

Tags: compiz, nautilus, conky

I am running 12.04 and have followed the instructions here:

[Is it possible to have a different background for each workspace?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/75998/is-it-possible-to-have-a-different-background-for-each-workspace)

to get a different wallpaper per workspace.  It works by disabling nautilus' drawing of the desktop and enables the Compiz wallpaper plug-in.  But since I've done that my conky will not longer appear.

Here's the relevant portion of it:

```
background yes
use_xft yes
xftfont Sans:size=10
xftalpha 0.9
update_interval 1.0
total_run_times 0

own_window yes
own_window_type desktop
own_window_title "conky"
own_window_hints undecorated,below,sticky,skip_taskbar,skip_pager

double_buffer yes
minimum_size 180 5
maximum_width 200
draw_shades no
draw_outline no
draw_borders no
draw_graph_borders no

default_color white
default_shade_color red
default_outline_color green

alignment top_right

gap_x 12
gap_y 28
no_buffers yes
uppercase no
cpu_avg_samples 2
override_utf8_locale no
```

Answer (score 0):

Edit this line `own_window_type desktop` to `own_window_type normal`. In most cases this will work. If it doesn't, change the line to `own_window_type dock`.

For more configuration:

http://conky.sourceforge.net/config_settings.html