# How do I make a compiz sphere look like a planet?

Tags: compiz, settings

I have read topics of people that what to style their compiz sphere like a planet and set a background image like space.

It definitely very good idea, but I have not been able to find a tutorial of how this is done (only some clips in youtube of people who have done this and a plugin, but it is not known to work work 12.04 version of Ubuntu).

I have set my settings of compiz manager, so I have a sphere now, but I need some help with the images that I need to set. Has anyone idea how these pictures should be created and who the compiz will concatenate them?

EDIT:

One of the answers here is showing how to set different images on each work space on Ubuntu 12.04 - [Is it possible to have a different background for each workspace?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/75998/is-it-possible-to-have-a-different-background-for-each-workspace)

What is left are the images - maybe someone will offer a way how to generate them?

Comment: You should watch Nixie's tutorials on Compiz(CCSM) on her youtube channel nixiedoeslinux.

Answer (score 0):

This is possible.

I used to use it on a 10.10 install.

I found the images you need hosted here: http://www.humus.name/index.php?page=Textures&ID=19

Make sure you grab the zip on the right hand side.

The only issue you'll come up against is you will need the compiz 'wallpaper' plugin which lets you set different papers for each workspace. The best you will manage on 12.04+ (so far anyway) is to set the cube caps and have a repeating wallpaper (pretty naff)

Hope you manage to get this set up, looks pretty cool with a stary skydome. I just wish the blue was a little more vibrant in those backgrounds.

Comment: Could you show your "Cube cabs" behavior settings because with 4 work spaces but using Sphere the top and bottom images are not matching in the correct way with these from the work spaces?