# How do I set up my workspaces to have different background images?

Tags: workspaces

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is it possible to have a different background for each workspace?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/75998/is-it-possible-to-have-a-different-background-for-each-workspace)

as the title states im trying to put in different images for each workspace (i have all the images ready) but every time i try to load up gconf-editor is says its not there or something... i went into the settings and i have a dconf but no gconf... also when i load up the dconf editor i cant find nautilus under the apps to change the desktop setting to use compizconfig to set the different workspaces. im currently running 12.10 and ive installed nautilus and compizconfig. i also tried installing the compizconfig extras but it says unable to locate compizconfig-fusion-plugins-extra. please help and thank you :D