# Different Wallpaper per Workspace - Ubuntu 12.10

Tags: 12.10

Ubuntu newbie here. I want a different wallpaper for each workspace. I tried CCSM and gconf-editor, and neither worked. And Compiz seems to crash on occasion. I'm using Ubuntu 12.10, and I can't find a single tutorial for 12.10 specifically.

Comment: You did not search very well then: http://askubuntu.com/questions/75998/is-it-possible-to-have-a-different-background-for-each-workspace see aendruk's answer :)

Comment: @Rinzwind This is not possible in 12.10 due to [this](https://bugs.launchpad.net/compiz/+bug/1020830) bug. The bug is fixed but is scheduled for release in compiz 0.9.9.0. The latest version available for update on 12.10 is 0.9.8.6.

Comment: @green7 - yeah - 12.10 will never get the fix - its fixed in raring though.

Comment: @green7 how is that different from what aendruk posted? ie: it is not possible in 12.10.

Comment: @Rinzwind Looked at his first answer. Should have posted this link: http://askubuntu.com/a/213514/83046.