# Desktop icons disappear when using wallpaper plugin

Tags: compiz, icons, desktop-background, plugins

When I enable wallpaper compiz plugin all icons disappear from desktop. How can I fix that?

Comment: Which icons are you talking about? The ones of the files on the desktop or those of Computer, Trash, etc?

Comment: The ones from desktop, not from dash.

Comment: Yes I understand but I'm wondering if it's normal files (such as images, documents, etc) or things like the Trash, Home Folder, etc. Which are not showing up? Can you see anything on the desktop?

Comment: I can't see anything on desktop. I had few custom .desktop icons.

Comment: Oh well a period in front of a filename hides them. That means they won't show up on your desktop. If you want to show them take away the .

Comment: *sigh*
For example, I have
World of Warcraft.desktop
Which is a wrapper for optirun/vgl/wine. Others are similar. No . at begining of name.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately, this is not possible. To get desktop icons back you will have to disable the Compiz `Wallpaper` plugin and allow Nautilus/Files to draw your desktop.

The Compiz Wallpaper plugin can draw your background, which can allow you do do some cool stuff (like have a different background image for each workspace). But this conflicts with Nautilus' ability to draw the desktop, and only Nautilus can display desktop icons.

For more information, see the answers to [this question.](https://askubuntu.com/questions/75998/is-it-possible-to-have-a-different-background-for-each-workspace) Apparently people have tried to make Nautilus draw a transparent desktop so you can see the images from the Compiz Wallpaper plugin behind the Nautilus icons, but those efforts have not yet been successful.

Answer (score 1):

## Ubuntu 13.04

I have tested it in Ubuntu 13.04 and its working.

```
sudo apt-get install unity-tweak-tool
```

[image]

[image]

I have also restarted the system and its working.

Comment: I need my custom icons and not home/network/rubbish bin/devices...

Comment: You need home folder with custom icon ?

Comment: Nooo. I have my own .desktop icons I created. See comments on question.

Comment: ok enable desktop icon, have one on desk like home icon and place your icon as well ..check if its working

Comment: Crashes on launch. http://paste.ubuntu.com/5654611/

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use Ubuntu Tweak and go to Tweaks → Desktop icons to turn them on and select which you want to show.

You can download Ubuntu Tweak [here](http://ubuntu-tweak.com/), or add a PPA and install it with the following commands:

```
 sudo add-apt-repository ppa:tualatrix/ppa
 sudo apt-get update
 sudo apt-get install ubuntu-tweak
```

[image]

Comment: It doesn't help.