# Different wallpapers for each workspace in Ubuntu 13.04. Fusion extra's not available. Is there another fix?

Tags: unity, 13.04, compiz, workspaces, desktop-background

I have been looking everywhere for an answer to my question. Tries just about every guide there is and went through all of the ubuntu forums.

This is not a duplicate question as the answers to the questions similar do not fit my question. I have tried all of the answers and none have worked. I have compiz extra's and there is no compiz fusion extras. I have the deskcube working with background image, but I want different wallpapers for each area.

I am trying to have four different wall papers for each workspace. I have compiz and have tried to find wallpapers under utility but the option is not there. I have all updates and extras installed that I can find.

Is this just something that isn't possible? I use my workspaces for different things and it gets annoying remembering which is which, even with a heading for each workspace.

I am running Ubuntu 13.04 currently and have looked all over for an answer. I have found questions with answers but none that seem to work. There is no wallpaper option in compiz but the fix to that is to get fusion extras and that won't work. Have tried to get sudo apt-get install compiz-fusion-plugins-extra with the terminal and it tells me 'unable to locate package'

If anyone knows please help me out!

Comment: This question has already been answered i guess .

http://askubuntu.com/questions/75998/is-it-possible-to-have-a-different-background-for-each-workspace

Comment: Have tried to add compiz fusion extras but the terminal tells me it is null and void

Comment: just add compiz-plugins .