# Unable to locate package compiz-fusion-plugins-extra

Tags: 14.04, software-installation, compiz

When I try to install compiz-fusion I get this messge "Unable to locate package compiz-fusion-plugins-extra". So I don't know why is that and I don't know how to fix it. If anyone can help me with this I really appreciate.

Thanx........

Comment: Is `compiz-plugins` the package you're looking for?

Answer (score 1):

compiz-fusion-plugins-extra is an old transitional dummy package from Ubuntu 12.04, and there is no package by the name of *compiz-fusion* in the Ubuntu Software Center for Ubuntu 14.04. There is however Compiz (compiz-core) which is installed by default in Ubuntu 14.04. If you could provide any more information on what it is you're trying to do with compiz-fusion then it would help to find what specific packages for that purpose are available in the Ubuntu Software Center for Ubuntu 14.04 (for example, compiz-plugins). When you install a package from the Ubuntu Software Center, it resolves all the package's dependencies for you, so that you don't get any error message like you got when trying to install compiz-fusion.

in order to add different wallpapers for different workspaces in Ubuntu 14.04 you need to install three packages from the Ubuntu Software Center - compiz-plugins, compizconfig-settings-manager and dconf-tools - and then follow the instructions from the answer by fossfreedom to the question: [Is it possible to have a different background for each workspace?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/75998/is-it-possible-to-have-a-different-background-for-each-workspace). Find the section of the answer called: [Ubuntu 13.04, 13.10 and 14.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/75998/is-it-possible-to-have-a-different-background-for-each-workspace/334224#334224) and then follow the step-by-step instructions as shown in the screenshots. Maybe you got the error message because you were trying to follow the instructions for Ubuntu 12.04 instead of for Ubuntu 14.04. If so, I have corrected that by giving you the second link to the instructions for Ubuntu 14.04.

Comment: Ah......anyway Karel thanx. I just wanted to add different wallpapers for different workspaces. So I did that.

Comment: @DraKula Your comment enabled me to determine a probable cause of your error message and how to fix it, which I have added to my answer.

Comment: @DraKula: if you think karel's answer is good, and represents a helpful solution to your problem, remember to check the green mark left of that answer's text field, to indicate it is a good answer, and so that others on AU may benefit from it.