# Repairing Unity after using Compiz and installing Lubuntu desktop

Tags: unity, apt, lubuntu, compiz, desktop-background

I will describe the steps I did before the issue appeared:

1. Running Unity, I wanted to have different wallpapers on each workspace. I followed [these steps](https://askubuntu.com/a/334224/148451).
2. After restart, no top panel appeared, no window borders etc. I had this issue before, after using Compiz (I hope I will not be tempted again to use Compiz).
3. I switched on `tty1`, and I installed `lubuntu-desktop`.
4. I added a new user `<olduser>clone`, on Lubuntu.
5. I logged in as `<olduser>clone` with Unity, which was working fine.
6. Being logged as `<olduser>clone` I managed to add different wallpapers on each workscape, without problems.
7. I didn't like how they were working, and I decided to uninstall Compiz.
8. I tried to uninstall `lubuntu-desktop` and its dependencies:

   sudo apt-get remove --purge lubuntu*
   sudo apt-get remove --purge abiword*

After restart nothing appears, just black screen. However, I had access to `tty1`. I installed back `lubuntu-desktop`.

Now Unity works fine, but combined with Lubuntu desktop.

I migrated all the files from the old user to its clone and renamed the `<olduser>clone` into `<olduser>`.

How can I remove `lubuntu-desktop` and its dependencies, without destroying Unity?

Comment: Maybe by uninstalling lubuntu-desktop, followed by re-installing Unity? Just what I would try... But I also have a somehow similar problem with Cinnamon on one user account.

Comment: @ByteCommander I already tried that `sudo apt-get install --reinstall ubuntu-destkop`, but it didn't solve the problem...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So you've `sudo apt-get remove --purge lubuntu*` and `apt-get install --reinstall ubuntu-destkop` already, but some of the CCSM you did before are probably still lingering around.

So I would:

1. Take a system back-up (Read [this Q&a](https://askubuntu.com/questions/569679/whats-a-good-back-up-strategy-for-1-desktop-pc))
2. Take a file backup (if your `/home` is on a separate partition)
3. **Remember that <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F7</kbd> brings you back here!**

   Go to TTY1 by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>.
4. `sudo apt-get purge ubuntu-desktop`
5. `sudo apt-get purge unity`
6. `sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop`
7. `sudo apt-get install unity`
8. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F7</kbd> to get back to the GUI login

**Why?** The purges will remove any lingering configuration settings and the installs will then reset everything to scratch

**Warning** This is for a plain Vanilla Ubuntu with Unity.  If you're running Kubuntu or Gubuntu, all bets are off! ;-)

Comment: I *fixed* it by reinstalling the system...

Comment: Have you made a system backup already???  Yesterday I accidentally deleted some printer stuff and instead of looking where the problem was, I just restored my system backup from 10 days ago, applied the updates, added some stuff back into bash.bashrc and 7 minutes later, I was back up-and-running!