# Different background for each workspace

Tags: 20.04, workspaces, desktop-background

In the past, setting the different backgrounds for each desktop was rather an easy thing to do.

I have not tried that for the past 2 years, and now I have been struggling for a few days to find a way to do it.

What is the "modern" way to set a different background for each workspace? Ubuntu 20.04 is in question.

Comment: I never knew it was easy to do. It is one of the major lacking features on many of the Linux desktops, afaik. For gnome Shell, there may be an extension.

Comment: [Is this what you’re looking for?](https://askubuntu.com/a/1089402/1222991) 

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is it possible to have a different background for each workspace?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/75998/is-it-possible-to-have-a-different-background-for-each-workspace)

Comment: @vanadium "on many of the Linux desktops," ....It is a piece of cake on KDE, which should be the second most popular linux DE.

Comment: Hi all, existing solutions are too old. Not valid for 20.x Ubuntu versions. None of them works.

Comment: [Walkpaper](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/1200/walkpaper/) works perfectly for me.

Comment: @pLumo it works in my case as well. Please add an answer so you get the bounty.

Comment: What's your DE/windowmanager?

Comment: @JacobVlijm The default one. Have not changed it after the installation. Shell version is I think 36.x.x.

Comment: It basically adds the ability to desktop right-click Change background. You change the wallpaper like you would do it normally, but the extension remembers what workspace you were on. To change different wallpapers, you have to switch to the corresponding workspace and change its background.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [Walkpaper Gnome Extension](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/1200/walkpaper/).

> Set different wallpaper for each workspace by having the wallpaper switch on workspace change.